# How to give apache web directory access to other FTP user where parent directory is restricted

Tags: linux, apache

I tried hard but not able to give access of web directory to other user for FTP.
Below are the directories which are under directory `/var/www/html`

```
1) nice_call
2) poor_call
3) great_call
```

/var/www/html is owned by apache user as well as all above mentioned directories is also owned by apache.

I just want to give read+write access to one more user named as `ftp_user` for directory `poor_call` not for other directories.
I am also ready to give 777 access to directory `poor_call` to resolve this issue.

Please note that I am having root access to execute any command to resolve this issue.
It will be great if someone can help on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new unix user called *ftpuser* and do the following for a practical work around.

*chown apache:ftpuser /var*

*chmod g+rw /var*

*chown apache:ftpuser /var/www*

*chmod g+rw /var/www*

*chown apache:ftpuser /var/www/html*

*chmod g+rw /var/www/html*

*chown apache:ftpuser /var/www/html/poor_call*

*chmod g+rw /var/www/html/poor_call*

Try FTP or SFTP, you are all set. If you are using FTP, make sure than your FTP program allows unix authentication otherwise you will have enable it from FTP config file.

**Update**: to jail a user to home directory.

If you are using Proftpd, just follow the steps.

*open up the ftp config file /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf*

*uncomment line DocumentRoot ~*

Note that this is valid for FTP only not SFTP.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Leo Prince but I just want to give access only to directory /var/www/html/poor_call not to parent directory.Please let me know above one solution will give only access /var/www/html/poor_call or it will give to parent as well